# Databricks problem accessing file _metadata

Tags: xml, pyspark, databricks, metadata, azure-databricks

I'm trying to access _metadata to get file modification time using the following instructions:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html

Here is my code:

```
df = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
    .options(rowTag='TAG2') \
    .options(nullValue='') \
    .load(xmlFile) \
    .select("*", "_metadata")
```

This works when I load csv file, but doesn't work with XML file. I get the error stating that there is no such column.

I am sure that the code loading XML contents works well.

Is this feature just not supported with XML files or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's possible that `com.databricks.spark.xml` class is not supporting adding the `_metadata` column. What elements of the `_metadata` are you looking for? It's possible to construct the info provided by `_metadata` column through other transformations.

Comment: @ARCrow I want to have file modification time

Comment: Use databricks runtime 14.3 with this code.
```df=spark.read.option("rowTag", "books").xml(xmlPath)
df.select("*", "_metadata.file_modification_time").display()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used slightly different approach since I decided to go with autoloader to ingest the files. I followed this example and read the files as binary and then convert them to xml
https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/kb/streaming/streaming-xml-example.html

I could access metadata without any issues.

Comment: Great! it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Since it's possible that the `com.databricks.spark.xml` class is not supporting adding the `_metadata` column, and it's confirmed that the value of the interest is the `file_modification_time` of the file, you can use `dbutils.fs.ls("<path to the folder containing the file>")`.
Here's an example of the output you can expect:

```
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/my_file.txt', name='my_file.txt', size=40, modificationTime=1622054945000)]
```

The `modificationTime` is in unix timestamp format.
If you have only one file in the directory, you can add the `file_modification_time` using `from_unixtime` transformation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

file_list = dbutils.fs.ls("<path to the folder containing the file>")
file_modification_unix_time = file_list[0].modificationTime
df = df.withColumn('file_modification_time', f.from_unixtime(f.lit(file_modification_unix_time)))
```

If you have multiple files in the directory, you can create a dataframe from the output of `dbutils.fs.ls` (let's call it `file_list_df`, add the file path for each record of `df` using `input_file_name()` transformation, and join `df` with `file_list_df`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

file_list = dbutils.fs.ls("<path to the folder containing the file>")
file_list_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([
        (file_elemen.path, file_element.modificationTime) for file_element in file_list
    ], ['filePath', 'modificationTime'])
    .withColumn('file_modification_time', f.from_unixtime(f.col('modificationTime')))
)
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('filePath', f.input_file_name())
    .join(file_list_df, ['filePath'])
    .select(df['*'], file_list_df['file_modification_time'])
)
```